# ERROR: Could not build wheels for numexpr, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: linux, arm, gensim, jpype, numexpr

I'm trying to install some requirements via **pip install -r requirements.txt**  on my raspberry pi4(ARMv7)

this is requirements.txt

```
...
kss==2.5.1
numpy==1.20.2
konlpy==0.5.2
scikit-learn==0.24.2
gensim==4.0.1
pyLDAvis==3.3.1
tweepy==3.10.0
...
```

It gave me below errors

**ERROR:**

```
   creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-38
          creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gensim
          creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gensim/models
          gcc -pthread -B /home/ops/mambaforge/envs/djangokeyword/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -O3 -isystem /home/opsroot/mambaforge/envs/djangokeyword/include -fPIC -O3 -isystem /home/opsroot/mambaforge/envs/djangokeyword/include -fPIC -I/home/opsroot/mambaforge/envs/djangokeyword/include/python3.8 -I/tmp/pip-install-t1lt0z56/gensim_d538d43beab94742ad28030592cee7e9/.eggs/numpy-1.22.3-py3.8-linux-aarch64.egg/numpy/core/include -c gensim/models/word2vec_inner.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gensim/models/word2vec_inner.o
          error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
          [end of output]
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for gensim
      Running setup.py clean for gensim
      Building wheel for JPype1 (setup.py) ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [56 lines of output]
          running bdist_wheel
```

---

```
gcc -pthread -B /home/ops/mambaforge/envs/djangokeyword/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -Wall -fPIC -isystem /home/opsroot/mambaforge/envs/djangokeyword/include -fPIC -isystem /home/opsroot/mambaforge/envs/djangokeyword/include -fPIC -Inative/common/include -Inative/python/include -Inative/embedded/include -Inative/jni_include -I/home/opsroot/mambaforge/envs/djangokeyword/include/python3.8 -c native/common/jp_array.cpp -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/native/common/jp_array.o -g0 -std=c++11 -O2
      error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for JPype1
  Running setup.py clean for JPype1
  Building wheel for numexpr (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for numexpr (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [31 lines of output]
```

also numexpr gave me same error.

I'm already try this command and some solution but It gave me same error.

> pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

My Python version is Python 3.8.10 and my os is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1058-raspi aarch64)

Is this gensim, JPype1 ,numexpr libraries don't support ARM architecture?
or Did i do something wrong?